# required for `Paginated<SelectStatement<FromClause<table>>>` to implement `for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, diesel::PgConnection, (Org, i64)>`

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to use diesel 2 `diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json","numeric"] }` to do some pagination. This is the pagination function look like:

```
pub fn org_query_tree<T>(request: &Json<OrgRequest>) -> PaginationResponse<Vec<OrgResponse>> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::org::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let predicate =
        crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::org::parent_id.eq(request.parentId);
    let query = org
        .filter(&predicate)
        .paginate(request.pageNum, false)
        .per_page(request.pageSize);
    let query_result: QueryResult<(Vec<_>, i64)> =
        query.load_and_count_pages::<Org>(&mut connection);
    let menu_responses = find_sub_org_cte_impl(&query_result.as_ref().unwrap().0);
    let total = 200;
    let page_result =
        map_pagination_from_list(menu_responses, request.pageNum, request.pageSize, total);
    return page_result;
}
```

this function query Organization info list from PostgreSQL 13 database, but this  line `let query_result: QueryResult<(Vec<_>, i64)> = query.load_and_count_pages::<Org>(&mut connection);` shows error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Paginated<SelectStatement<FromClause<dolphin_schema::org::table>, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<dolphin_schema::org::table>>, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<&diesel::expression::grouped::Grouped<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<dolphin_schema::org::columns::parent_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>>>>>: QueryFragment<Pg>` is not satisfied
   --> src/service/permission/org/org_service.rs:120:15
    |
120 |         query.load_and_count_pages::<Org>(&mut connection);
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `QueryFragment<Pg>` is not implemented for `Paginated<SelectStatement<FromClause<dolphin_schema::org::table>, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<dolphin_schema::org::table>>, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<&diesel::expression::grouped::Grouped<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<dolphin_schema::org::columns::parent_id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, i32>>>>>>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `QueryFragment<DB, SP>`:
              <&'a T as QueryFragment<DB>>
              <() as QueryFragment<DB>>
              <(T0, T1) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
              <(T0, T1, T2) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
              <(T0, T1, T2, T3) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
              <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
              <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
              <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
            and 705 others
    = note: required for `Paginated<SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<table>>, NoDistinctClause, ...>>` to implement `for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, diesel::PgConnection, (Org, i64)>`
    = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/reddwarf-admin/target/debug/deps/reddwarf_admin-7813535ed8ebf672.long-type-13811969663519505074.txt'
note: required by a bound in `Paginated::<T>::load_and_count_pages`
   --> /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust_wheel-8476ff1b418e67f8/2b74fc9/src/common/query/pagination.rs:43:19
    |
43  |             Self: for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, PgConnection, (U, i64)>,
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Paginated::<T>::load_and_count_pages`
```

I have read this similiar issue https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/discussions/3505 and recheck my code, did not have any clue, this is the pagination code defined like:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::LoadQuery;
use diesel::query_builder::{QueryFragment, Query, AstPass};
use diesel::pg::Pg;
use diesel::sql_types::BigInt;
use diesel::QueryId;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

pub trait PaginateForQueryFragment: Sized {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64, is_big_table: bool) -> Paginated<Self>;
}

const DEFAULT_PER_PAGE: i64 = 10;

impl<T> PaginateForQueryFragment for T
    where T: QueryFragment<Pg>{
    fn paginate(self, page: i64, is_big_table: bool) -> Paginated<Self> {
        Paginated {
            query: self,
            per_page: DEFAULT_PER_PAGE,
            page,
            is_sub_query: true,
            is_big_table,
            offset: (page - 1) * DEFAULT_PER_PAGE
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, QueryId, Serialize, Deserialize, Default)]
pub struct Paginated<T> {
    pub query: T,
    pub page: i64,
    pub per_page: i64,
    pub is_sub_query: bool,
    pub is_big_table: bool,
    pub offset: i64,
}

impl<T> Paginated<T> {
    pub fn per_page(self, per_page: i64) -> Self {
        Paginated { per_page, ..self }
    }

    pub fn load_and_count_pages<U>(self, conn: &mut PgConnection) -> QueryResult<(Vec<U>, i64)>
        where
            Self: for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, PgConnection, (U, i64)>,
    {
        let per_page = self.per_page;
        let results = self.load::<(U, i64)>(conn)?;
        let total = results.get(0).map(|x| x.1).unwrap_or(0);
        let records = results.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect();
        let total_pages = (total as f64 / per_page as f64).ceil() as i64;
        Ok((records, total_pages))
    }

    pub fn load_and_count_pages_total<U>(self,conn: &mut PgConnection) -> QueryResult<(Vec<U>, i64, i64)>
        where
            Self: for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, PgConnection, (U, i64)>,
    {
        let per_page = self.per_page;
        let results = self.load::<(U, i64)>(conn)?;
        let total = results.get(0).map(|x| x.1).unwrap_or(0);
        let records = results.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect();
        let total_pages = (total as f64 / per_page as f64).ceil() as i64;
        Ok((records, total_pages,total))
    }
}

impl<T: Query> Query for Paginated<T> {
    type SqlType = (T::SqlType, BigInt);
}

impl<T> RunQueryDsl<PgConnection> for Paginated<T> {}

impl<T> QueryFragment<Pg> for Paginated<T>
    where
        T: QueryFragment<Pg>,
{
    fn walk_ast<'b>(&'b self, mut out: AstPass<'_, 'b, Pg>) -> QueryResult<()> {
        out.push_sql("SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM (");
        self.query.walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
        out.push_sql(") as paged_query_with LIMIT ");
        out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&self.per_page)?;
        out.push_sql(" OFFSET ");
        out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&self.offset)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, QueryId)]
pub struct QuerySourceToQueryFragment<T> {
    _query_source: T,
}

impl<FC, T> QueryFragment<Pg> for QuerySourceToQueryFragment<T>
    where
        FC: QueryFragment<Pg>,
        T: QuerySource<FromClause=FC>,
{
    fn walk_ast<'b>(&'b self, mut out: AstPass<'_, 'b, Pg>) -> QueryResult<()> {
        // self._query_source.from_clause().walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub trait PaginateForQuerySource: Sized {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64, is_big_table: bool) -> Paginated<QuerySourceToQueryFragment<Self>>;
}

impl<T> PaginateForQuerySource for T
    where T: QuerySource {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64, is_big_table: bool) -> Paginated<QuerySourceToQueryFragment<Self>> {
        Paginated {
            query: QuerySourceToQueryFragment {_query_source: self},
            per_page: 10,
            page,
            is_sub_query: false,
            is_big_table,
            offset: (page - 1) * DEFAULT_PER_PAGE
        }
    }
}
```

I also read the diesel official document from here https://diesel.rs/guides/extending-diesel.html, still did not figure out where is going wrong. I have already define the `load_and_count_pages`. What should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: This line `Self: for<'a> LoadQuery<'a, PgConnection, (U, i64)>,` set constrain or condition that require you pass param at your caller correctly `query.load_and_count_pages::<Org>` I saw your type `Org`  u can try simple query with (String, String) ..may work